# Restrict options on outlook VBA: How to get emails sent on a specific time frame

Tags: vba, outlook

We have a time zone issue from 3 sites located all over the world, each office has a different time zone.
I am trying to get all emails that were sent on a specific time frame from my inbox but i was only able to do so by the time the emails were received (my time), can anyone assist me finding how to filter items by time they were sent?

```
filterCriteria = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" + Format(dateFrom, "dddddd hh:nn AMPM") + "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '" + Format(dateTo, "dddddd hh:nn AMPM") + "'"
        Set filterItems = mysubfolder.Items.Restrict(filterCriteria)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SentOn` property in your query. Keep in mind that time zones make no difference at all - Outlook stores all dates in UTC, and all date/time properties in the Outlook Object Model are returns in your local time zone.

Comment: So how can i get the time it was sent? (on the sender location time zone)

Comment: There is no "SentOn" Option on restrict

Comment: Juts use the [SentOn] property in your query. Outlook does not preserve any original time zone info from the original message. You might be able to extract it from the MIME headers of the original messages (e.g. Date: Mon, 25 Apr 2016 10:06:07 -0700)